# How do I enable TLS 1.0,1.1,1.2 for a simple HTML page?

Tags: html, https

I am trying to make an HTML page which is HTTPS and uses TLS protocol 1.0,1.1,1.2 and  Encryption: 128-Bit and 256-Bit with Content: Text HTML page, PDF, RSS.

It is a simple website and I went on my Registry Editor and enabled TLS 1.0,1.1 and 1.2. But how do I implement on the webpage?

I am trying to create my own self-signed certificate but i don't see the option for TLS. And how do i run it in a webpage in my computer file directory?

Comment: The HTML page does not know anything about the protocol - it is just a text file. It "doesn't care" whether it is transferen using HTTP/S, FTP, SMB, or over an USB stick. HTTPS/TLS configuration is something the **webserver** (or an application server) cares for. You probably should rephrase your question and also provide more details about the use case and problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I am trying to create my own self-signed certificate but i don't see the option for TLS. And how do i run it in a webpage in my computer file directory?